# Returning a list as multiple elements

Tags: python, set, python-itertools

I am using a power set generator to see the intersections between sets. The generator returns lists that are different combinations of sets. I have tried the following:

```
overlapped = [set.intersection(g) for g in powerset(listOfSets)]
```

but g is a list, and set.intersection doesn't take lists; it simply takes multiple elements that are all sets.

Is there a built in function, or a way to break down a list of n-elements into n separate return elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (the `*` operator) to accomplish this.

```
>>> foo = [set([1,2]), set([2,3]), set([2,4])]
>>> set.intersection(*foo)
set([2])
```